# HTTP POST in Python

Tags: python, http, post

I am trying to convert a HTTP POST into Python and am not sure how to go about doing this.

I have the HTTP Request:

```
POST vision/v1/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation =true
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.projectoxford.ai
Content-Length: 95
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
{ "Url": "exampleurl.com"}
```

As well as the URL request and need help on whether or not I am doing this correctly.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = "urlrequest.com"
values = {"Url":
            https://exampleurl.com}
data = url.lib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
```

I am getting an `HTTTPError`:

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.
```

Comment: `req` is undefined. Show correct code.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, nor are you actually using `data` after encoding it. Please at least provide us with code that is free from syntax errors so we can determine if not using `data` could be the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed a line of code. It is corrected to show my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send JSON with additional header entries:

```
url = "http://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true"
data = json.dumps({'Url': 'exampleurl.com'}).encode('utf-8')
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••',
}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: What does the json.dumps() do? I am getting "TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str."